# The area between coordinate axes and tangent to $f(x)$ is $2x f(x)$. Is this correct?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I was checking the answers of [the coordinate axes has minimum area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823129/the-coordinate-axes-has-minimum-area) question.

In short, the mentioned question asks the minimum area formed by a tangent to $y=4-x^2$ and coordinate axes. I noticed [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959921/115728) to the question mentioned an interesting property:

> Using similar triangles, it can be proven that the area of the triangle is twice the product $xy$ where $y=f(x)$.

This property seems valid for the mentioned question, as well as $y=a/x$ and several other forms that I tried. However, I cannot prove or disprove.

Can we prove or disprove the property? In what conditions is the property valid?

Comment: I don't think the statement is true. Take a tangent to $y=4-x^2$ at the point $(2,0).$ The triangle has vertices $(0,0),$ $(2,0),$ and $(0,8),$ with area $8$, but $xy=0.$

Comment: @David well, the triangle is degenerate at that point. the slope is zero, and the tangent crosses x-axis at infinity. However, your case seems to be true: $xy=0$, if the area calculation was correct, then area would be calculated as infinity.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015695/the-method-to-calculate-area-between-fx-and-coordinate-axes

Comment: You're thinking of the triangle with vertex at $(0,4).$ I considered using that one, since it's a more dramatic example, but I did not want to deal with degenerate triangles. At $(2,0)$ the slope is $-4$ so we get an ordinary (but still too large) triangle.

Comment: Yes, you are right both against your counter-example, and how I misread your comment. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another answer from your link it is proven that:
$$
A=\frac{(4+x^2)^2}{4x}\ne2x(4-x^2).
$$

Comment: Ok, the area formulation is not aligned. However, the algorithm seems to find the optimal solution.
I have posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015695/the-method-to-calculate-area-between-fx-and-coordinate-axes